# Credit Card Type N/A in magento admin sales->order

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, sales, payment-methods

Credit card type is, of course, required field on the front end and the customer can't checkout with selecting one of options.

So how could the database get a NULL value in cc_type for an order? If anyone can explain what files are associated with receiving an order and inserting it into the database, that might help me figure out what's going on. The perplexing part is, this doesn't happen for every order, just a few over the course of a day.

Thanks!

Comment: Some payment method will store the information they received from the api without validating to make sure that all the correct field are return before saving them and in rear cases they don't return all the original card info (i.e last4 or card type). Please provide more info on which payment api you are have an issue with

Comment: even atlast 4 digits are also not displaying and i am using eway rapid payment gateway(australian store)

Comment: Did you try contacting the developer?

Comment: I am working on this i am the developer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, depending on the type of payment method used, Magento will store the payment information under `sales_flat_order_payment.cc_type` and other CC-related columns or all of the information in the `additional_information` column. For example, Authorize.net payment information, I believe, is stored in the latter as a serialized array.

Comment: I am using eway rapid payment gateway.